# How to find shortest path in a weighted graph using networkx?

Tags: python, python-2.7, networkx

I'm using the `networkx` package in `Python 2.7 Enthought distribution` to calculate shortest paths between a network of seaports. It's working fine to calculate the distance using `dijkstra_path_length`, but I also need to know what route it has found using `dijkstra_path` (as an aside, I think it should be faster to run if I calculate the path first, then calculate the length from the path rather than running Dijkstra's algorithm twice on the same data). However the path function is failing, saying `list indices must be integers, not str`.

Here's the code that produces the error. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
import networkx as nx

# Create graph
network_graph = nx.Graph()
f_routes = open('routes-list.txt', 'rb')
# Assign list items to variables
for line in f_routes:
    route_list = line.split(",")
    orig = route_list[0]
    dest = route_list[1]
    distance = float(route_list[2])
    # Add route as an edge to the graph
    network_graph.add_edge(orig, dest, distance=(distance))

# Loop through all destination and origin pairs
for destination in network_graph:
    for origin in network_graph:
        # This line works
        length = nx.dijkstra_path_length(network_graph, origin, destination, "distance")
        # This line fails
        path = nx.dijkstra_path(network_graph, origin, destination, "distance")
```

I'm getting the following in the traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jamie.bull\workspace\Shipping\src\shortest_path.py", line 67, in <module>
    path = nx.dijkstra_path(network_graph, origin, destination, "distance")
  File "C:\Enthought\Python27\lib\site-packages\networkx\algorithms\shortest_paths\weighted.py", line 74, in dijkstra_path
    return path[target]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Experimenting a bit, it appears that `nx.dijkstra_path` raises a misleading exception when the origin and destination nodes are the same:

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> g = nx.Graph()
>>> g.add_edge('a', 'b', distance=0.3)
>>> g.add_edge('a', 'c', distance=0.7)
>>> nx.dijkstra_path_length(g, 'b', 'c', 'distance')
1.0
>>> nx.dijkstra_path(g, 'b', 'c', 'distance')
['b', 'a', 'c']
>>> nx.dijkstra_path_length(g, 'b', 'b', 'distance')
0
>>> nx.dijkstra_path(g, 'b', 'b', 'distance')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    nx.dijkstra_path(g, 'b', 'b', 'distance')
  File "C:\Users\barberm\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\networkx\algorithms\shortest_paths\weighted.py", line 74, in dijkstra_path
    return path[target]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

So just make an explicit test whether `destination` and `origin` are the same, and handle it separately when they are.

Comment: A complete newby quenstion: the "weights" or "distance" in this case, is it lower is easier or the other way around? A higher weight makes an edge more preferable for a path?