# Graph Networkx Python

Tags: python, graph, python-3.4, networkx

I'm using networkx in my code to calculate djikstra's shortest path between 2 nodes.

First of all, I've this to add the distance between 2 nodes:

```
g.add_edge(nodeA,nodeB,distance)
```

After that, i call Dijkstra's method:

```
nx.dijkstra_path(g,'source','target')
```

and then i get:

```
['nodeA','nodeC','nodeK','nodeB']
```

Everything works good, but i still not figure out how to calculate the total distance between nodeA and nodeB like this:

```
total distance = edge(nodeA->nodeC) + edge(nodeC->nodeK) + edge(nodeK->nodeB)
```

Can somebody help me, please?

Many thanks!

Comment: This seems related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14353743/how-to-find-shortest-path-in-a-weighted-graph-using-networkx if so and it answers your question I will close this as a duplicate

Comment: Sorry, man... It works perfectly. :) You can close now, please.

Comment: No worries, I've voted to close it, hopefully others will see this and it will get enough votes for it to be closed as a duplicate. Don't delete it, it helps others who search for questions to find the best match that point to the same answer